# Boost error conversion from ‘boost::filesystem3::path’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string

Tags: c++, string, boost, std

I have code:

```
std::string firstFile = boost::filesystem::path(first->name()).leaf();
```

But get error:

```
error conversion from ‘boost::filesystem3::path’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string
```

How can i fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
std::string firstFile = boost::filesystem::path(first->name()).leaf().string();
```

also note that the `leaf` function is deprecated and is removed in Boost.Filesystem V3.

Comment: See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#path-deprecated-functions for a list of deprecated  functions